# nutch2.3+mysql+solr ClassNotFoundException

Tags: mysql, nutch

I wrote mysql config to `gora.properties` and update sql lib in `ivy.xml`.

but when I run the command:

```
bin/crawl urls/seed.txt Test http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr 2
```

it throws exception:

```
[root@li257-46 local]# bin/crawl urls/seed.txt Test http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr 2
Injecting seed URLs
/home/work/nutch2/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt -crawlId Test
InjectorJob: starting at 2015-05-13 03:25:35
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls/seed.txt
**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/ipc/ByteBufferOutputStream
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.getDataStoreClass(StorageUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.ipc.ByteBufferOutputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
Error running:
  /home/work/nutch2/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/seed.txt -crawlId Test
Failed with exit value 1.**
```

First, I think the avro jar not add, but I found the jar in lib:

```
/home/work/nutch2/runtime/local/lib

[root@li257-46 lib]# ls

avro-1.7.6.jar

avro-compiler-1.7.6.jar

avro-ipc-1.7.6.jar

avro-mapred-1.7.6.jar
```

Can you help me?